# deleting data from the database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with deleting data from the database, I made table that will show the name and password of the registered users. and beside them a delete link.
and when I press the delete link it gives me an error.

**here is the viewTheUsers.php page**

```
<html> 
<head>
<title>the users</title> 
</head> 
<body>
<table  width ="650" align ="center" border ="2" >     
<tr>
<th width="60">User No </th>    
<th>User Name  </th>   
<th>User Password </th>   
<th>Delete User </th> 
</tr>    
<?php
mysql_connect("hostName","userName","password");
mysql_select_db("db_name");
$Thequery = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$run = mysql_query($Thequery );
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)){
$The_id = $row[0];    
$The_name = $row[1];  
$The_pass = $row[2];  
?>
<tr> 
<td><?php echo $The_id; ?></td>    
<td><?php echo $The_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $The_pass; ?></td>
<td><a href="delete.php?deleting=<?php echo $The_id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**and here is the delete.php page:**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("hostName","userName","password");
mysql_select_db("db_name");
$deleting_id = $_GET['deleting'];
$Thequery = "delete from users where id = '$deleting_id' ";
if (mysql_query($Thequery )){
echo "<script>window.open('viewTheUsers.php?deleted = user has been    deleted!!!','_self')</script>";      
}
?>
```

**the massege error says:**

Notice: Undefined index: deleting in C:\wamp\www\delete.php on line 6

Comment: are you aware that mysql.* functions are depreciated?

Comment: What is line 6 of delete.php?

Comment: That error suggests that you have `$_GET['del']` in your script instead of `$_GET['deleting']`. Check for typos.

Comment: you should use your "viewTheUsers.php" with a form tag.

Comment: beware of `<img src="http://yoursite.com/delete.php?deleting=1">`

Comment: What is line 6 of delete.php? it means this code $deleting_id = $_GET['deleting'];

Comment: You have a typo somewhere. Check where you have used `$_GET['del']` or something and change it to `deleting`.

Comment: I added form tag and it still doesn't work

Comment: i have checked your code. it is working exactly fine.

i am getting $_GET["deleting"] value.

Comment: @user2442835 have u check Url in browser? Does it has "delete.php?deleting=id" ?

Comment: when I press the link delete I find this Url "localhost/delete.php?deleting=1" and with this message Notice: Undefined index: deleting in C:\wamp\www\delete.php on line 6

Comment: and the 6 line is this code:  $deleting_id = $_GET['deleting'];

Comment: you need to check your ini setting. check the memory limit in php.ini

Comment: I think you are right because when I try to open php.ini it says that this shortcut has been moved or changed

Answer (score 1):

Have a care that there are numerous problems with this code. One of them being the **injection** problem you have for just putting whatever is in the get variable "deleting" straight into your database query.

Also, that window.open call opens an invalid url (I suppose it might work, but you should probably do some sort of url-encoding for the spaces etc). To be nitpicking, your variable naming is really non-standard (first letter is mostly lowercase, and why prepend 'the' everywhere?, but that isn't really a biggy).

In the end, check out the line 6. The error means "your are trying to access a value in an array, but the index you are using ('del') isn't there at all. Probably you check `$_GET['del']` and it isn't set.

Comment: I am sorry the message error that I get is:  Notice: Undefined index: deleting in C:\wamp\www\delet.php on line 6 so it is deleting and not del

Comment: Please consider cut/paste, this notice also has a typo in it. The point is the same though: `$_GET['deleting'];` doesn't exist. `var_dump` your get array, check out your url, and fix the fact that your delete ID is empty. Probably a typo somewhere. Start debugging now you know the reason for the notice.